# $a^{(b^c)} \mod m$ where $c$ can be very very large

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the following problem.
I need to find the value of
$$
    a^{(b^x)} \bmod m
$$
where $a,b$ are integers and
$$
    x = \pmatrix{n\\0}^2 + \pmatrix{n\\1}^2 + ... + \pmatrix{n\\n}^2  
$$
the value of $n$ can be upto $10^5$
and $m = 1000000007$ which is a prime
Also note that its $a^{b^x}$ which is not equal to $a^{bx}$
Also by solving $c$ it comes out to be $\pmatrix{2n\\n}$
also $\pmatrix{2n\\n}$ satisfies the relation 
$$
    a_n = a_{n-1}  (4n-2)/n  
$$
where  $a_0 = 1$
I have reached the fact that $a^{b^c} \bmod m$ is equivalent to
$$
    a^{b^d \bmod \phi(m)} \bmod m  
$$
where $d=c \bmod \phi(\phi(m))$

but i am unable to calculate the value of $c$ as it involves a denominator term and modulo inverse is not possible since $\phi(\phi(m)) = 500000002$ is not a prime.
Can anyone suggest me any approach or any possible thing that I missed.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use Chinese Remainder Theorem, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/n-choose-k-bmod-m-using-chinese-remainder-theorem)

Comment: It looks like you're going back and forth between $x$ and $c$ -- all occurrences of those two letters are meant to be the same variable, right?

Comment: Why is no-one else voting to close this as a duplicate of the question Quixotic linked to?

Comment: [Abstract duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172317/) asked by the same user.

Comment: well don't worry got it!! thnks so much for your help..