# Pattern in Pascal's triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, number-systems

### **Updated question**

> This "reverse" pattern can be plotted as a function of a triangle, read
>   by rows:
>
> $$ T(n,k) = (\delta)^k F\binom{n}{k} \left\lfloor f(t(k)) \right\rfloor ,\delta\in\{1,-1\}.$$
>
> The $T(n,k)$ here represents an "(alternating) transformation of
>   Pascal's triangle":
>
> - The $t(k)$ is the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), to
>     normalize the border of scatter plot to $y=x$.
> - We can apply some border function $f(x)$, which gives a new border to the pattern.
> - $F$ represents the transformation of the Pascal's triangle. The "reverse" transformation is given by $F := F^{(d)}_b(x)$: equals $1$
>     if the $d$*th* digit of $x$ is $1$ in base $b$, and $0$ otherwise.
> - $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, which makes up the Pascal's Triangle.

For example, here is the alternating ($\delta=-1$) "reverse pattern" with linear border $f(x)=x$, in number base $b=10$ for first digit case $d=1$: (Read $T(n,k)$ with described parameters by rows, and draw the terms as a scatter plot)

[image]

Or a similar example, but now $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ (just the border changing example):

[image]

> **Question:** How can we "explain" this pattern?
>
> As of this update, my question boils down to: How can we describe these "arc" like, fractal like, patterns, in these plots of the "reverse/inverse" Pascal's pattern?
>
> Can we relate them to similar structures, or "mathematically describe" and relate to some relevant results (theorems,...)?
>
> Also, if we increase the base $b$, we get the "zooming in" effect. See gif at the end of the post.

For example, if the $F$ was the "normal Pascal's pattern (not reverse/inverse Pascal's pattern given above)", now given by taking the binomial coefficients modulo some prime number, then this pattern represents the Sierpiński triangle (also called Sierpiński gasket):

[image]

In this particular instance, we have $\delta=1$ and modulo $b=2$ for the now $F_b(x):=x \pmod b$ transformation (Instead of the $F^{(d)}_b(x)$ transformation), and linear ("outer") border $f(x)=x$.

The answer to "explain this pattern" in this case, was given [in a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/887398/318073) regarding this pattern. - It was related to the [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem).

> But my question here is, considering this new $F$ ("inverse") pattern
>   - how can we "explain" it? - Like the "normal pattern" is "explained" by the fact that it gives a well known fractal, the Sierpiński
>   triangle, and this process of converting the Pascal's triangle to the
>   Sierpiński triangle, relates to Lucas's theorem.

---

---

---

### Pre-update question contents

**Known pattern**

In general, numbers in pascals triangle produce *sierpinski-triangl-like* fractals. Some examples can be seen in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1926965) and are explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/887398).

If we take the last digit of numbers (binomial coefficients) in the pascals triangle, and color the $\ne0$ digits white, we get the following image shown below; (First $1024$ rows)

[image]

Where this process is equivalent to taking $\binom{n}{k}\bmod m$ (where $m=10$ for this case) and coloring nonzero results. This is what was observed in the linked question/answers, for values of $m$ in general. (This is equivalent to taking last digit of binomial coefficients in some number base $m$)

Note that multiple patterns seem to be overlapping in the picture above. This is discussed in the linked answers. Only prime numbers $m$ produce *clean* patterns, and composite numbers like $10$ above are a combination of multiple prime patterns.

The pattern below does not care if number base (in context of first/last digit) is prime or not. It seems that, that variable in the pattern below, is used as a "zooming" factor to the picture of the pattern. *See the gif at the end of the post.*

---

**"Reverse" pattern**

But what if we take the first digit, instead of the last one, in some number base?

For decimal case, we have the following image, for comparison to the above: ($b=10$)

[image]

Where we colored the pixel if the first digit of the binomial coefficient is $"=1"$. (Since $0$ can't be the first digit) Similar pattern holds for any other single digit, in any other number base.

> Why does this pattern appear in the pascals triangle, in all
>   number bases?
>
> Can it be somehow mathematically described or linked to any other
>   things?
>
> Like the first patterns links pascal triangle with
>   sierpinski-triangle-like fractals, which can be explained for prime numbers by the Lucas' theorem (*see linked answers*) ?

You can observe the first $32$ number bases for the first $256$ rows: (10 images per second)

*(Starting at base $3$ since in binary we have only one nonzero digit)*

[image: desc]

When the number bases are increasing, it looks like its "zooming into the tip".

You can also see the number [base 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bhWS.png) compared to [base 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJCAh.png) .

Also see, that if we pick another digit $"= d"$ for our $"=1"$ condition, we get a "corrosed" effect on the pattern for bigger digits. See digits $1\dots9$ for $b=10$ example [here as a gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/f9eFf15ZNd5g3JStkC/giphy.gif).

---

Comment: Simply beautiful!

Comment: Things like these are why people did maths- there is so much beauty in it!

Comment: The prominent arcs are almost certainly related to the fact that each entry in the triangle is the sum of the two above it.