# Find $\binom{80}{40}\bmod 2000$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, modular-arithmetic

> Find $\displaystyle\binom{80}{40}\bmod 2000$.

So far, I've found that $\displaystyle\binom{80}{40}$ is divisible by $2^2$ and $5^1$, so the answer isn't $0$. Usually, with smaller numbers, I would split the $\bmod 2000$ into $2^4$ and $5^3$, find the answer through brute force for each of those, then use the Chinese Remainder theorem. But $80$ and $40$ are too big for this.

Comment: Do you have to do the computation by hand? Computer algebra tools such as Sage seem to have no trouble computing $\binom{80}{40}$ through brute force; it only has 24 digits.

Comment: You could build Pascal's triangle in the usual way but always mod 2000.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95507/19006) help?

Comment: The actual value is $0\text{x}654$ (base $16$ for terrible obfuscation).

Answer (score 0):

Since $${80 \choose 40} = \frac{80\cdot 79 \cdot 78 \cdot 77 \cdot ...\cdot 41}{40 \cdot 39 \cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot ... \cdot 1}$$ we can cancel the terms in the denominator with terms in the numerator leaving a factor of $2$, so $2^{40}$ is a factor of the answer. It only remains to see how many factors of 5 remain.  $75, 65, 55$, and $45$ are all factors, so at least $5^4$ is a factor.  As a result, the expression is definitely a multiple of $2000$, so modulo $2000$ the answer is $0$.

EDIT: A few minutes later I realized my mistake, and returned to find several people pointing it out: only the numbers down to 21 in the denominator cancel.  That still leaves $$\frac{2 \cdot 79 \cdot 2 \cdot 77 \cdot 2 \cdot 75 \cdot...\cdot 2 \cdot 41}{ 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot...\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$ which gives $20$ factors of $2$ in the numerator and $10 + 5 + 2 + 1 = 18$ factors of $2$ in the denominator, so only $2^2$ is a factor. For the $5's$, we have $5$ factors in the numerator and $4$ in the denominator, so it is a multiple of $5$ but not $5^2$.

So now we have $$\frac{79 \cdot 77 \cdot 3 \cdot 73 \cdot...\cdot 43 \cdot 41}{ 19 \cdot 9 \cdot 17 \cdot 3 \cdot 7...\cdot 6 \cdot 3}$$. Continuing to cancel factors, we find $3^{8}$ in the numerator and $3^8$ in the denominator, and so forth. We end up computing ${80 \choose 40}$ and then can find the answer by inspection.

Comment: 2^40 does not divide it, you can verify with a calculator. Same with 5^4.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor that is incorrect. The answer is [not $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%2880%2C+40%29+mod+2000).

Comment: But there are $40$ factors downstairs, and only $20$ even factors upstairs. I think that your method is the preferred one, but I’m unconvinced that your count is correct.

Comment: Notice that the numerator now has $40$ terms (of which only $20$ are even, as @Lubin points out), _not_ $80$. And therefore, you cannot have $2^{40}$ in the numerator after performing the division.

Comment: OP is correct about the first part: the number is a multiple of $2^2$ and $5^1$, but is not a multiple of $2^3$ or $5^2$.

Comment: Kummer’s Theorem clearly shows your computations are incorrect. The highest power of $2$ that divides $\binom{80}{40}$ is the number of carries when adding $80-40=40$ and $40$ in base $2$. In base $2$, $40=10100$, so you get exactly two carries. So $\binom{80}{40}$ is a multiple of $2^2$ but not of $2^3$.

Comment: My apologies everyone, I caught my mistake but you caught it faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I built Pascal's triangle in a spreadsheet program, but always reducing mod 2000. There's never a need to keep more than the result mod $2000$. The result I get is $1620$.

- Cell A2: `0`
- Cell A3: `=A2+1` and carry down to Cell A82 with value $80$.
- Cell B1: `0`
- Cell C1: `=B1+1` and carry rightward to Cell AP1 with value $40$.

Now these are the indices of Pascal's triangle. For $\binom{n}{k}$, $n$ is in column A and $k$ is in row 1.

- Cell B2: `1` and carry all the way down.
- Cell C3: `=MOD(B2+C2,2000)`, carry all the way rightward, and then all the way down, filling out the table.

Now Cell AP82 is $\binom{80}{40}$ mod $2000$. It gives $1620$.

To do this by hand, at first it may seem like you would calculate about $80\cdot40=3200$ cell entries mod $2000$. But actually you would only need to compute about $\frac14$ of those entries, as represented in blue here:

[image]

The red is all $0$. The orange is not needed to reach the $\binom{80}{40}$ cell. And the green can be written using symmetry from the blue. So this would take about $800$ additions mod $2000$ plus some other less signiicant labor.

---

But we an do better, because there is the identity $$\binom{80}{40}=\sum_{n=0}^{40}\binom{40}{n}^2=\binom{40}{20}+2\sum_{n=0}^{19}\binom{40}{n}^2$$

So actually if we can get Pascal's triangle down to the first half of the 40th row, then we can square mod $2000$ about 20 times, double, sum the results mod $20$ and have our answer.

A similar analysis reveals that you would need to calculate about $400$ of the entries of Pascal's triangle mod $2000$ for this approach.